# Disabling scrolling to end of text in JEditorPane

Tags: java, swing, scroll, jeditorpane, htmleditorkit

Hi
I used a JEditorPane with HTMLEditorKit to showing HTML text with ability to wrap text.
The problem is when I set it's content using .setText method it automatically scrolls to the end of that text.
How can I disable this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this trick to save the cursor position before the `setText()` and then  restore it once you've added your text to the component:

```
int caretPosition = yourComponent.getCaretPosition();
yourComponent.setText(" your long text  ");
yourComponent.setCaretPosition(Math.min(caretPosition, text.length()));
```

Comment: `yourComponent.setCaretPosition(Math.min(caretPosition, text.length()));` would be better to prevent `IllegalArgumentException` if the new text is shorter than the previous. To scroll to the first line: `yourComponent.setCaretPosition(0)` which would actually be easier than my answer :) (+1).

Comment: Do note, however, that this may produce unexpected results when the `JEditorPane` is read-only: the user does not set the caret position here, and scrolling may move the caret out of view. However, `setCaretPosition(0)` will work as expected for a read-only `JEditorPane`. See haferblues's answer for a solution that will preserve the position for a read-only `JEditorPane`.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
final DefaultCaret caret = (DefaultCaret) yourEditorPane.getCaret();
caret.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.NEVER_UPDATE);
//!!!!text must be set AFTER update policy has been set!!!!!
yourEditorPane.setText(text);
```

Comment: This is the only answer which will preserve the position for a read-only `JEditorPane`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this after `setText`:

```
Rectangle r = modelToView(0); //scroll to position 0, i.e. top
if (r != null) {
  Rectangle vis = getVisibleRect(); //to get the actual height
  r.height = vis.height;
  scrollRectToVisible(r);
}
```